# How to fix Horizontal particles in plane?

Tags: particles

[image]

[image]
I have been following the BlenderGuru [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhYtJ_VmvXE) here on how to create a grassy meadow. Everything so far has worked pretty well okay but suddenly my grass particles have begun to appear [horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpYHr.jpg). I've looked around a lot and I really haven't found a way to fix this. I'd like my particles to stick vertically out of the ground instead of staying on the side. Here is a link to my .BLEND file, just in case, but I can also provide more screenshots of my settings if you need it.

[image]

Comment: There is no link to blend file, please post it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @LukeD I only have 1 rep so couldn't post a 3rd link, here is the file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1871/

Comment: I've added answer and also blend file to your post but it need to be approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set in *Velocity* tab *Normal* to 0 (if it's to straight try higher values) and *Emitter Object* > *Z* to 1.

[image: grass settings]

If my answer was good enough, consider accepting it or/and upvoting.

Comment: Cheers man, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Whoops, my bad! New to posting here :D